# await any async method and (event or boolean)

Tags: c#, async-await, manualresetevent

I have this code :

```
ManualResetEvent EventListenerStopped;
...
while (true)
{
    IAsyncResult iar = this.ListenerHttp.BeginGetContext(ProcessRequest, null);
    if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { this.EventListenerStopped, iar.AsyncWaitHandle }) == 0)
        return;
}
```

Basically it waits for any of two events :

- if a request is received, it processes it and wait for the next one.
- if EventListenerStopped is raised, it exits the loop.

This code has been running in production beautifully for quite some time now.

I wanted to try and convert it to the new await/async mechanism and can't seem to find a good simple way to do it.

I tried with a boolean the caller can turn to false. It obviously does not work as it exits the loop only after a new request has been received and processed :

```
bool RunLoop;
...
while (this.RunLoop)
{
    HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await this.ListenerHttp.GetContextAsync();
    ProcessRequest(listenerContext);
}
```

I'm wondering if it's even possible to rewrite my simple old-style loop with async/await. If yes, would someone be willing to show me how ?

Comment: Have you tried to stop the listener instead of using a bool?

Comment: @Micky I understand they're not the same. My point was : is there a way to achieve something similar with async/await (I was confusedly thinking of some kind of Task.WaitAny() where one of the tasks would be checking the raise of some boolean...)

Comment: @alexm I haven't tried it myself but read somewhere on SO that this should not be done as it would break any request currently processed (well the ListenerContext object is passed to a threadpool for processing in my case...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not specific to async-await, but you're probably looking for `CancellationToken` (which is used with a lot of async-await code anyway):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx

The 'BlockingOperation' example code seems similar to what you're trying to do:

> ```
> void BlockingOperation(CancellationToken token) 
> { 
>    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
>    //register a callback that will set the MRE 
>    CancellationTokenRegistration registration = 
>       token.Register(() => mre.Set()); 
>    using (registration) 
>    { 
>       mre.WaitOne(); 
>       if (token.IsCancellationRequested) //did cancellation wake us? 
>           throw new OperationCanceledException(token); 
>    } //dispose the registration, which performs the deregisteration. 
> }
> ```

Comment: I read about CancellationToken which I agree could do the trick. Yet it appears much more complicated than the two lines of code I currently have. I'm slowly coming to the conclusion async/await is not always a better way to do things...

Comment: I tend to agree. These days I pretty-much use async-await exclusively for all IO-bound stuff, but I still find the pattern you're trying to replace helpful in some circumstances, notably for the worker method for a separate thread.  I don't know the full context of your code, but it might well be an example where it's not necessarily a good idea to use async-await just because it's the new thing.

Comment: (I'm exactly in the case of a separate worker thread) Thanks for sharing your thoughts !

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I must point out that the old code is not quite correct. When dealing with the [`Begin`/`End` pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx), you *must* always call `End`, even if you want to (or did) cancel the operation. `End` is often used to dispose resources.

If you do want to use cancellation, a `CancellationToken` is likely the best approach:

```
while (true)
{
  // Throws an OperationCanceledException when cancellationToken is canceled.
  var request = await this.ListenerHttp.GetContextAsync(cancellationToken);
  ProcessRequest(request);
}
```

There are alternatives - it's *possible* to do something like `Task.WhenAny`, and there are even implementations of `AsyncManualResetEvent`, so it's possible to create an almost line-by-line equivalent to the old code, but IMO the cancellation token approach would be cleaner.

For example, using [`AsyncManualResetEvent` from my AsyncEx library](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx/3.0.1/net45/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncManualResetEvent):

```
AsyncManualResetEvent eventListenerStopped;
while (true)
{
  var task = GetContextAndProcessRequestAsync();
  if (await Task.WhenAny(eventListenerStopped.WaitAsync(), task) != task)
    return;
}

async Task GetContextAndProcessRequestAsync()
{
  var request = await this.ListenerHttp.GetContextAsync();
  ProcessRequest(request);
}
```

But personally, I would change to use `CancellationToken`.